# write a Java method that determines if any pair of students has the same course

Tags: java

this is an onsite interview question for java engineer:

> Given an array of type Student with the property Course, write a Java method that determines whether any pair of students in the array has the same course. Be sure to return a boolean value of true if a match is found. Please try to provide the most efficient solution possible assuming a very large number of students.
>
> List the test method names that you would want to implement for the
>   above code. Provide the implementation for at least one of these

I can't find the most efficient solution,  does 
anyone have a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: What is your input, is it pair of students or a array of students ?

Answer (score 5):

You can only loop once if you use an additional data structure, namely a Set:

```
boolean check(Student[] array) {
    HashSet<String> courses = new HashSet<String>();
    for(Student tmp : array){
        if(!courses.add(tmp.getCourse()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need a set really.  See my solution and tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @AmirAfghani You're not wrong, your idea just has different characteristics (yours modifies the array, is `O(nlogn)` instead of `O(n)`, and uses `O(1)` extra memory). Yours also relies on some kind of ordering on `course` (which is not a problem here, but more generally it may be).

Comment: I would think the overhead of creating a new set of size n each time would be a big deal.

Comment: The set will be worst case `O(n)` extra memory while keeping the time complexity at `O(n)`. The sorting approach is always `O(nlogn)` time and `O(1)` space and destroys your original array (so if order is relevant it's not an option).

Comment: Why would you say the original array is destroyed?  There are in memory algorithms that can be used for sorting.

Comment: Order is not maintained. It's called a destructive operation, so I used the word destroyed. Modified would have been a better choice of word.

Comment: The problem description does not call for order to be preserved.  In general I agree with your comment about not modifying the data in any way during a 'read' type operation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `hashmap`? It is very efficient. You can build a hashmap for pair of students who has the same course, then use contain value to output if they are in the map. for `N` students, there would be `N*(N-1)/2` pairs, so given any pair you just look at the hashmap, then return true or false.

use Amir Afghani's method:

```
boolean sameCourse(Student s1, Student s2) { 
    if(s1.getCourse().equals(s2.getCourse()) { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

then in two loops you put all the pairs into a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Comparable` interface for this.

You can compare two objects based on any of their property in this.

You can find more help on this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array using the course attribute.  Then you can walk the array only once and quickly identify duplicates.

```
boolean hasStudentsWithSameCourse(Student[] students) {
    Arrays.sort(students, new CourseComparator());
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length-1; i++) {
       if(sameCourse(students[i], students[i+1]) { 
           return true;
       }
    }

    return false;
}

boolean sameCourse(Student s1, Student s2) { 
    if(s1.getCourse().equals(s2.getCourse()) { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

I prefer this solution over creating a new `Set` each time this routine is invoked.  Given that this is Java, my solution produces no GC pressure, and O(nlogn) runtime vs O(n) does not merit the difference in memory cost O(1) vs O(n). The problem states:

> assume a large number of students.

A colleague of mine just brought up the following point:

> Given an array of type Student with the property Course, write a Java
>   method that determines whether any pair of students

None of the solutions as written return the right answer if the same student shows up in the array more than once.

Comment: An optimisation would be instead of counting just keep track of the previous one you saw. If the previous one is the same as the current one then you have two of them, so you can return `true`. If you never return `true` then you can return `false`.

Comment: yeah - i see what you're saying.

Comment: Your last test should be `students[0]` and `students[students.length-1]`. As it is you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for `students[students.length]`.

Comment: You mean -2, and - 1, right?  How do you figure its students[0]?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it was sorted! You don't need to do any extra check at the end there, just return false. The `-2,-1` case will be checked in the loop.

Comment: True true, I am tired tonight.

Comment: My intuition is that this is O(n ln n) (due to sorting) whereas Peter Ivanov's above is O(n). His requires more space (for the set of courses), but I think it's reasonable to think that the number of courses is reasonably small.

Comment: Tim, its stated in the problem to assume a large number of students

Comment: @TimMacdonald If number of courses is less than number of students then the answer is always true (by the pigeonhole principle). There must be more courses than people to make this interesting, and there are a lot of people from the problem statement.

Comment: I'm sort of surprised this answer hasn't generated any upvotes.  Lets see if I can at least be proven wrong or dismissed. Great question!

Comment: @AmirAfghani I have not upvoted because I don't think a method which is merely checking for something should modify the thing it's checking. Your method either modifies the original array or else uses `O(n)` extra memory (which makes the set approach superior).

Comment: OK - thats a strong argument that I can agree with.  I'll leave the answer up here for learning purposes.

Comment: I was going to say that `a large number of students` =/=> `a large number of courses`, but I hadn't thought of the pigeonhole principle. Good call, @mange.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I think this example will help you..
```

// Time complexity is o(n) and hashset add and contain  method complexity o(1)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class StudentSimilarCource {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Student s1 = new Student(1, "anuj", "science");

        Student s2 = new Student(1, "amit", "botany");

        Student s3 = new Student(1, "anuj", "math");

        Student s4 = new Student(1, "anuj", "science");

        Student[] stuarr = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };

        StudentSimilarCource obj = new StudentSimilarCource();
        System.out.println(obj.findTwoStudent(stuarr));

    }

    private boolean findTwoStudent(Student[] stuarr) {

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        for (Student s : stuarr) {
            if (set.contains(s.getCourse()))
                return true;
            else
                set.add(s.getCourse());
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class Student {
    int id;
    String name;
    String course;

    public Student(int id, String name, String course) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

}
```